# Selector from material-ui doesn't work for me?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I try to implement example of [material-ui selector](https://material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/) and got code-fragment from [github example](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)

```
import React from "react";
import {withStyles} from "material-ui/styles";
import Select from "material-ui/Select";
import styles from "../../overtimesStyles";

class DivisionReport extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: "",
  }

  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({selectedOption});
    // selectedOption can be null when the `x` (close) button is clicked
    if (selectedOption) {
      console.log(`Selected: ${selectedOption.label}`);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {selectedOption} = this.state;

    return (
      <Select
        name="form-field-name"
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={[
         {value: "one", label: "One"},
         {value: "two", label: "Two"},
         {value: "333", label: "One"},
         {value: "444", label: "444"},
         {value: "555", label: "555"},
         {value: "666", label: "666"},
        ]}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(DivisionReport);
```

But there is no items for selection which I expected to see: 
[image]

Can you suggest why I met with this issue?

p.s. top component, which use DivisionReport is:

```
const OvertimesReport = ({handleChangeSelection, selectedOption, classes}) => (
  <div className={classes.workarea}>
    <Card>
      <CardContent className="overtimes">
        <DivisionReport handleChangeSelection={handleChangeSelection} selectedOption={selectedOption}/>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  </div>
);
```

style is:

```
workarea: {
  margin: "0px 5%",
},
```

Comment: Why are you importing `Select` as `import Select from "material-ui/Select";`? Didn't you use `react-select`? I.e. `import Select from "react-select";`

Comment: @Tholle it solved my issue, please make comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to import the `Select` component from `material-ui/Select`, but you should import if from the `react-select` package instead:

```
import Select from "react-select";
```

Also note that the value key of an `option` is named `value` and the label key is named `label`, not `valueKey` and `labelKey`.

```
<Select
  name="form-field-name"
  value={selectedOption}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  options={[
    {value: "one", label: "One"},
    {value: "two", label: "Two"},
    {value: "333", label: "One"},
    {value: "444", label: "444"},
    {value: "555", label: "555"},
    {value: "666", label: "666"},
   ]
  }
/>
```

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov Could you include the entire file in the question, i.e. include the styles and imports?

Answer (score 0):

```
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
```

Then in the render:

```
   <Select
      native
      name="form-field-name"
      value={selectedOption}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
   >
     <option key="1" value="1"> 1 </option>
     <option key="2" value="2"> 2 </option> 
     <option key="3" value="3"> 3 </option>  

   </Select>
```

Try this way, and let me know how it works